# java.lang.RuntimeException: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon is not a valid external type for schema of struct<513:int,549:int>

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I want to create a dataframe with this schema:

```
 |-- Col1 : string (nullable = true)
 |-- Col2 : string (nullable = true)
 |-- Col3 : struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- 513: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- 549: long (nullable = true)
```

Code:

```
val someData = Seq(
      Row("AAAAAAAAA", "BBBBB", Seq(513, 549))
    )

val col3Fields = Seq[StructField](StructField.apply("513",IntegerType, true), StructField.apply("549",IntegerType, true))

val someSchema = List(
  StructField("Col1", StringType, true),
  StructField("Col2", StringType, true),
  StructField("Col3", StructType.apply(col3Fields), true)
)

val someDF = spark.createDataFrame(
  spark.sparkContext.parallelize(someData),
  StructType(someSchema)
)

someDF.show
```

But `someDF.show` throws:

> ERROR Executor: Exception in task 0.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 0)
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Error while encoding:
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: scala.collection.immutable.$colon$colon is
>   not a valid external type for schema of struct<513:int,549:int> if
>   (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]).isNullAt)
>   null else staticinvoke(class org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String,
>   StringType, fromString,
>   validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0,
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 0, Col1), StringType), true, false)
>   AS Col1#0 if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row,
>   true]).isNullAt) null else staticinvoke(class
>   org.apache.spark.unsafe.types.UTF8String, StringType, fromString,
>   validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0,
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 1, Col2), StringType), true, false)
>   AS Col2#1 if (assertnotnull(input[0, org.apache.spark.sql.Row,
>   true]).isNullAt) null else named_struct(513, if
>   (validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0,
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 2, Col3),
>   StructField(513,IntegerType,true),
>   StructField(549,IntegerType,true)).isNullAt) null else
>   validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0,
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 2, Col3),
>   StructField(513,IntegerType,true), StructField(549,IntegerType,true)),
>   0, 513), IntegerType), 549, if
>   (validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0,
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 2, Col3),
>   StructField(513,IntegerType,true),
>   StructField(549,IntegerType,true)).isNullAt) null else
>   validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(validateexternaltype(getexternalrowfield(assertnotnull(input[0,
>   org.apache.spark.sql.Row, true]), 2, Col3),
>   StructField(513,IntegerType,true), StructField(549,IntegerType,true)),
>   1, 549), IntegerType)) AS Col3#2  at
>   org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.encoders.ExpressionEncoder.toRow(ExpressionEncoder.scala:291)

**Edit:**

513 and 549 should be the subcolumn names rather than the values. Here is an example of an output I expect:

```
someDF.select("Col1","Col2","Col3.*").show

+-----------+--------+------+------+
|       Col1|    Col1|   513|   549|
+-----------+--------+------+------+
| AAAAAAAAA |  BBBBB |    39|    38|
+-----------+--------+------+------+
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data you have and the Schema you have are not same,
The schema you want to create is here how you create

```
val schema = StructType(
  Seq(
    StructField("col1", StringType, true),
    StructField("col2", StringType, true),
    StructField("col3", StructType(
      Seq(
        StructField("513", LongType, true),
        StructField("549", LongType, true)
      ))
    )
  )
)
```

Schema:

```
root
 |-- col1: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col2: string (nullable = true)
 |-- col3: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |-- 513: long (nullable = true)
 |    |-- 549: long (nullable = true)
```

This gives you the schema you want

You can get the data as below and apply the schema

```
val someData = Seq(
  Row("AAAAAAAAA", "  BBBBB", Row(39l, 38l))
)

val someDF = spark.createDataFrame(
  spark.sparkContext.parallelize(someData), schema
)

df.select("Col1","Col2","Col3.*").show
```

Output:

```
+---------+-------+---+---+
|     Col1|   Col2|513|549|
+---------+-------+---+---+
|AAAAAAAAA|  BBBBB| 39| 38|
+---------+-------+---+---+
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. Although, this is not accurately what I need. I've edited my question to exaplain my case better. Please have a look.